# Encrypting strings write to file and then decrypt file in PHP

Tags: php, file, encryption, php-openssl

I'm having a slight problem where I am using "openssl_encrypt" to encrypt a string of text that contains HTML, writing that string to a file, and then in a **separate page**, I am decrypting the entire file using "openssl_decrypt".  I've made sure to use the same encryption key, same method, and same iv.  I imagine this is something that, as a newbie to encryption, I just can't see.  Thank you in advance for any help!

Here is some example code:

```
//An example of the string
$string = "<div class='mod'><div><span class='datetimestamp'>On 06/28/2016 at 04:32:09 PM, ** modified a record with id of \"5\" in the \"results\" table:</span><br><span class='record-label'>Prev Record:</span>jobnumber='none', dropdate='07/06/2016', eventdate='07/16/2016', dealership='ABC Nissan', pieces='3700', datatype='DB', letter='t'";

//The encryption
$encrypt = openssl_encrypt($string, 'AES-256-XTS', '93jkak3rzp72', 1, '45gh354687ls0349');
$file = fopen("logs/2016-06-28.log", 'a');
fwrite($file, $encrypt);
fclose($file);


//The decryption - DONE IN A SEPARATE PAGE
$file = @fopen("logs/2016-06-28.log", "r");
if ($file) {
    while (($data = fgets($file)) !== false) {
        $decrypt .= openssl_decrypt($data, 'AES-256-XTS', '93jkak3rzp72', 1, '45gh354687ls0349');
    }
}
```

Comment: Works for me.  add `echo $decrypt;` And check that you can reed/write `logs/2016-06-28.log`

Comment: If you are just encrypting a file XTS is not the best encryption mode, CBC is more commonly used. XTS is designed for sector by sector disk encryption.

Comment: E_p, the encryption and decryption are done on separate pages.  And the files are being written to, and read from, fine.

Comment: Zaph, I will give CBC a try and post back.  Thanks!

Comment: CBC will not fix the problem but is a better mode, see my answer for the fix.

Comment: If you are trying to append additional encrypted data to a file add that information to the question.

Comment: You need to either write each encrypted segment in its own line (or other delimiter) or keep track of the length of each encrypted segment. Otherwise you won't know where one string ends and the other begins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the issue is that you are trying to append additional encrypted data, that will not generally work for several reasons, a major one being that AES is block based and there will most likely be padding. Many modes use some form of chaining and this will also fail when appending encrypted data.

You are opening the file you are writing to in append mode, that is not what you need, instead use write `w` mode. That is causing each encryption to be appended to the previous data and the reason the first tie works but subsequent times. If you examine the file length after each encryption it will be apparent what is happening.

You need to use:

```
$file = fopen("logs/2016-06-28.log", 'w');
```

From the [php fopen docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php):

> '**w**'    Open for writing only; **place the file pointer at the beginning** of the file and truncate the file to zero length. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.
>
> '**a**'    Open for writing only; **place the file pointer at the end** of the file. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it. In this mode, fseek() has no effect, **writes are always appended**.

Comment: This will only keep one log entry in the file though as each time you open the file it is truncating it. So as long as you only ever want to see the last entry this will work fine.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use `fgets()` as it only gets a single line from a file at a time and you can't split up an encrypted string and decrypt single pieces at a time.

You could use `fgets()` but you need to read in everything and store it in an variable and then after you have everything decrypt.

Or you can simply use something like `file_get_contents()` to get the entire file's content and then decrypt.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I originally tried using `file_get_contents()` but the decryption still fails.  The decryption runs perfectly on the first string that is written to the file, but on any string that is written to the file thereafter, the decryption fails and various symbols appear.

Comment: That is because you can't do that. You can't append more data to an encrypted file and decrypt it all at once. 

If you want to do that then yes you will need read it in line by line and decrypt each individual line separately. However, if you string contains a line break then you are going to have a line break in your file. So you will need some other way other than line breaks to distinguish separate entries onto the file.